I am unable to connect to an ec2-instance with ssh
It's throwing an error while ssh connection.
I tried to login with EC2 serial console, it works for me, but I'm unable to connect with internet and I'm unable to install any packages.
Logs
I rebooted that instance and got these logs, I also stopped my instance and restarted it, but that didn't work for me.
Is there any way to connect this instance or get backup from that instance?

Not sure what you're asking in terms of backup, but you can create an AMI from an EC2 instance or take a snapshot of any attached EBS volumes.

For issue with connection via ssh, check the inbound rules in security group attached to your instance. Check if port 22 is open for your IP. If not then add a rule allowing your IP to connect on port 22.
Seems like your instance is in a private subnet. For it to communicate with the internet and download packages you'll need a NAT gateway in public subnet. See here how to setup a NAT gateway.
